# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id_ibu' cannot be null

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

insert into `ibuhamils` (`id_ibu`, `berat_badan`, `tinggi_badan`, `lila`, `t_darah`, `keluhan`, `tgl_periksa`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, 54, 159, 20, 120/80, Tidak Ada, 2023-08-25, 2023-08-25 11:57:40, 2023-08-25 11:57:40)

help me solve this problem!!!

**my controller**

```
public function store(Request $request){
        
         // menerima data request
         $ibuhamil = [
            'id_ibu' =>$request->id_ibu,
            'berat_badan' => $request->berat_badan,
            'tinggi_badan' => $request->tinggi_badan,
            'lila' => $request->lila,
            't_darah' => $request->t_darah,
            'keluhan' => $request->keluhan,
            'tgl_periksa' => $request->tgl_periksa,
        ];

         Ibuhamil::create($ibuhamil);

         Alert::success('Data Berhasil Ditambah');
 
         return redirect()->route('ibuhamil')->with([
             'success' => 'Data Berhasil Di Tambah'
         ]);
    }
```

**My Views**

```
  <form action="{{ route('admin.ibuhamil.store')  }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                <div class="card-header py-3">
                    <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">{{ isset($ibuhamil) ? 'Form Edit Data Ibu Hamil':'Form Tambah Data Ibu Hamil' }}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="id_ibu" style="font-weight: bold;">Nama Ibu</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="id_ibu"  style="width: 100%;" required >
                            <option selected="selected" value="">-- Nama Ibu --</option>
                            @foreach($users as $datas)
                                <option value="{{ $datas->id_ibu}}">{{ $datas->nama_ibu }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="font-weight: bold;>
                        <label for="tinggi_badan">Tinggi badan</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="tinggi_badan" name="tinggi_badan" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="font-weight: bold;>
                        <label for="berat_badan">Berat Badan</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="berat_badan" name="berat_badan" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="font-weight: bold;>
                        <label for="lila">LILA</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="lila" name="lila" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="font-weight: bold;>
                        <label for="t_darah">Tekanan Darah</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="t_darah" name="t_darah" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-group" style="font-weight: bold; for="ket_imun">Keluhan</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="keluhan" name="keluhan"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" style="font-weight: bold;>
                        <label for="tgl_periksa">Tanggal Periksa</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="tgl_periksa" name="tgl_periksa" value="">
                    </div>                 
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
                        <a href="{{ route('ibuhamil') }}" class="btn btn-warning">Kembali</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Make sure `id_ibu` is fillable on your model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <option value="{{ $datas->id_ibu}}">{{ $datas->nama_ibu }}</option>
```

Mistake is here, here be the value is empty, and on request the value didn't get it.

→ If not required then change the allow nullable value for this.

→ $users model what is the field name and use the same in the blade loop,

What is the primary column name in this table you printing here **$datas->id_ibu** rather it would be like **$datas->id** or whatever name that column in the user table.

May be your solution is below

```
  <option value="{{ $datas->id}}">{{ $datas->nama_ibu }}</option>
```

Comment: tq sir, its work

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing 1 or all of 3 things. First, you have an error in you html where you are missing a quote. Also you have an option that is "" an empty string and though the element is required. I believe that is still valid from an html perspective.

```
<div class="form-group" style="font-weight: bold;>
```

should be

```
<div class="form-group" style="font-weight: bold;">
```

Second, I would need to see your Database Schema, but unless your id_ibu is a string as well as a foreign key or key for something else. You probably don't want to be setting it like that. Also from the database or MySql Error, you are plainly not passing it to the create function or I cannot remember if the id is a fillable attribute and unable to take that as the parameter.

You should also validate the request data. In laravel you can reach for a validator where you can define the requirements and the type of data passed back foreach key. Also should update model to reflect $primarykey, $incrementing, and $keytype.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
public function store(Request $request){
  dd($request->id_ibu);   // if value is not coming then check your blade file why the id_ibu is not coming }
```

Step 2 :
if value is coming then check the App\Models\Ibuhamil.php
**$fillable = ['id_ibu']**
orelse
**protected $guarded = [];**

Comment: how I do not understand. what are the steps?

Comment: null // app\Http\Controllers\IbuHamilController.php:34

Comment: @foreach($users as $datas)
                                <option value="{{ $datas->id}}">{{ $datas->nama_ibu }}</option>
                            @endforeach so id is not coming let's try this   Change the {{ $datas->id_ibu}} to {{ $datas->id}}